# Javascript regex not matching last char in form

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this simple regex to catch the last instance of 'turn to 123' in a form (I have another regex for the main body):

```
currenttext=currenttext.replace(/([^>])(turn\s+to\s+)(\d+)$/i,"$1<tt ref=\"$3\">$2$3</tt>");
```

which for example substitutes
turn to 123...
with

```
<tt ref="123">turn to 123</tt>...
```

...in live form input.  However it only works if there is some form of character *after* the number 123, whether it be a carriage return or a visible character, which I cannot fathom since the $ end of match anchor clearly has no other character prior to the memory pattern for the numerical digits.  Without a subsequent character I get this result:

```
<tt ref="12">turn to 12</tt>3
```

i.e. it fails to catch the last digit completely.  I have tried putting the $ anchor inside the memory parens but made no difference.

Comment: In what browser? It works for me, under node, Chromium and Firefox.

Comment: I can't replicate this behaviour, it works in regexr: http://regexr.com?3031a

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Running the following code in a javascript console `"foo turn to 123".replace(/([^>])(turn\s+to\s+)(\d+)$/i,"$1<tt ref=\"$3\">$2$3</tt>");` returns `
"foo <tt ref="123">turn to 123</tt>"`. Could you post the code that is causing the problem.

Comment: Firefox latest.  It just occurred to me to show where I get the form content from, maybe I've got this wrong? var currenttext=document.editbook.reftext.value; where reftext is the name of the editable textarea

Comment: `function autotag(){
  var currenttext=document.editbook.reftext.value;

  // catch EOF anomoly ('?' match before ([^<])screws up regex)
  currenttext=currenttext.replace(/([^>])(turn\s+to\s+)(\d+)$/i,"$1<tt ref=\"$3\">$2$3</tt>");`

Comment: I would check a string dump and possibly a hex dump of `currenttext` and see if there are any characters between "12" and the "3", like a Zero-width non-breaking space, a `<span></span>` or something else.

Comment: ok it does work on a standalone test, I have no idea why it's not working in my main document...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am quite certain there is nothing wrong with this regex. You must be getting the wrong text as the input `currenttext`. You can verify this by checking currenttext before running this code (either console.log(currenttext) or alert(currenttext), or something like that).

Things to look out for:

- Are you using substring(...) with (begin, end) instead of (begin, end+1)?
- Are you matching the last character as a separate group in a RegExp?

Comment: I have no idea myself now where or what was causing the error... but it just went away.  Think it's fair to say there was nothing wrong with the regex anyway.